# Domain of real valued functions

Tags: functions

Can we take complex numbers in domain of a real valued function?
eg $f(x)=$ $x^4$
If we take $x=i$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$

$f(i)=i^4=1$
Hence can we conclude that the domain can be extended to complex numbers in real valued functions?

Comment: Not every complex number will produce a real value when substituted into that function.

Comment: Yes but some will do, so will that be included in the domain of real function?

Comment: If you are defining your function to be a real-valued, you cannot put imaginary numbers. Real valued function means a function that is defined on real numbers.

Comment: Real-valued function means a function which takes real values in its range. Such a function need not have a domain subset of rea numbers. For example, $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ as $f(x+iy)=x.$